# Better review audits, better review ban tools

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, review-audits, review-suspension

Review audits are a hard problem. It's difficult to programmatically generate hard audits with a high enough degree of confidence to act on them. This results in a lose-lose situation at the moment - people (rightly) complain about the poor ones that are generated, but they also usually feel formulaic and easy to game if you spot the inconsistencies in how they get generated. Fixes to this system of audit generation are just tweaking the sensitivity of a [ROC curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic).

On the flip side of the coin, the moderator tools for handing out review bans are clunky. It shouldn't be a big deal to say "this wasn't right", and let the system take it from there. (As an example, there are often three users involved in letting spam slip through, to message and ban each takes two copy and paste operations per user, plus digging around to determine appropriate lengths).

**This is a feature request for a "convert to audit" tool for moderators.**

When we see a post that clearly should have been picked up during the review process, https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/XXXXXX is the starting page. I'd propose that the UI for this feature is run off that page and includes:

1. A "what should have happened" information capture.

   On suggested edits that's a reject reason, for other queues it's probably pretty much the standard flagging dialog. This can be used as a learning point later.
2. A "who was clearly wrong" information capture.

   This is probably a checkbox next to each reviewer. Pre-populated based on #1.
3. An if/how long to ban incorrect reviewers option.

   This should be pre-filled automatically. There really isn't any sense in making humans guestimate how this person has reviewed historically when there's already data that's a great starting point.
4. A "promote to audit" checkbox.

   This would push the review item, anonymous but otherwise unchanged, into a pool of manually picked audits. The new pool is likely to be small so it would not replace, but rather augment the current mechanism with better audits that are both broader and deeper in coverage than anything automatically generated can do.

Items that slip through are (or should be) edge cases - exactly where moderators are expected to be acting. Please can we have a tool that can help fix three issues in the current setup simultaneously.

Answer (score 68):

First, as a counterpart to your suggestion, I'd like to once again state that we should [have a means of disputing audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790). Users should be able to identify problematic audit cases, and moderators should be able to remove them from circulation. We should also be able to nullify audit failures due to these bad cases. That would eliminate almost all legitimate complaints we see about audits on Meta, and make good reviewers more comfortable with the process.

To your main point: yes, the workflow around dealing with users who approve spam or other trash in review is a real pain right now. I dealt with two flags on this already today, and here were the steps I had to take:

- See flag on someone approving spam
- Look at the post, determine it was spam, and see that someone clicked "Looks Good" on it in review
- Try to determine if this was the first such review abuse by an individual, so I pull up their profile and look to see if they've been banned before (taking 4-5 clicks to do so, plus a new tab in my browser)
- I might also need to look at other recent reviews of theirs, so I look at their profile, but that only shows reviews on non-deleted posts. I then have to dig up the moderator-specific review tools to find all of their reviews, but to do so I have to handcraft a URL based on their user ID. Even then, I can only look at reviews in specific queues, and can't pick out other audits they may have failed.
- I decide to ban them, and have now decided on a proper interval, based on their review history. I remember the ban link is in the moderator dashboard, so I click on that, only to have the process time out due to the overload of flags on Stack Overflow at present. Again, I have to dig up the URL from my notes and type it in by hand (now in a third browser tab).
- I have to copy the profile URL from the second tab into my third tab, copy the review URL from the first tab into the third, select a ban duration, and type a detailed reason why we're banning someone for a particular review.

This is why it often takes us a while to respond to custom flags asking us to ban particular users for bad reviews, especially if such flags don't come with specific terrible reviews as examples.

It would greatly speed this up to have an addition to the moderator menu on reviews cases. From that review case, we could choose to ban select reviewers based on that review, it could pre-populate the ban reason with the URL to the review and suggest a ban duration based on the number of previous review bans by that user.

There could also be a link on there or on the user profile where moderators could see in a list all recent reviews by a user, including ones on deleted posts, with passed or failed audits called out on that list. This would allow us to determine at a glance if this was a slip-up by a good reviewer or a pattern of carelessness, coloring our decision to ban or not and for how long to ban.

Also, even after all of this, our custom ban reasons often mean little since [most reviewers won't be able to see the post got banned for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed). They won't be able to see the spam or whatever it was they approved, since we will have deleted it by then. They need to be able to refer to this when banned, or when failing an audit on it. That's yet another thing that should be improved.

Now when it comes to creating audit cases, I don't have as much of a problem with the current setup. If someone approves spam and it gets through review, I can tag it with my own spam flag. This destroys the post, feeds it into the anti-spam system, and immediately makes it an audit case. For truly terrible posts, we already have the means of making them audit cases through self-approved flags. However, as I stated in the beginning, we don't currently have the opposite: the means to remove an audit case, and I think that's a more pressing problem.

Comment: yeah that would explain why there is so many robo-reviewers around... if it took me so much effort just to catch and ban someone I wouldn't bother neither...

Comment: "(...)have a means of disputing audits." - audit the audit!

Comment: I thank you, sir, for mentioning the need for a formal method to dispute bad audits. MSO and MSE posts that discuss proposals like this seem to generate a lot of "But we're auditing the audits, it's turtles all the way down!" kind of comments, but I think that's misguided. I've failed audits before from flagging opinion-based or off-site resource questions that got lots of upvotes and became a "known good" post. A method for contesting this would make many reviewers a lot happier with the process. I think a review ban for too many false disputes could minimize the noise it generates, too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make moderators create audits.  Have the audits self create.

Step 1: Add a review power estimate for each reviewer.

`(Accept rate)*(Reject rate)*log_2(Number of reviews)` for a first approximation.  (accept*reject) is a measure of how much information their reviews generate.  The log portion grants more power to more experienced reviewers, without going crazy.<sup>1</sup>

Step 2: Find reviews that are disputed, especially by a high review-power by low review-power users.  Call these "interesting edge cases".

Step 3: Feed these reviews as tests to high "review power" users.  See if they produce a significant consensus (view the reviewers as coins that accept randomly based off of their history, and/or poke a statistician.)

Step 4: Take the ones that passed step 3, and call these audit candidates.  Add them to the global audit pool.

While the above scales well with large N (constant work to produce audit candidates for **everyone**), I'd be concerned about small N, and quite possibly the number of people doing reviews may be small?

---

<sup>1</sup>: A 50-50 rate generates an information per vote of 0.25.  A 95-5 rate is 0.0425, or almost 6 times less.  The 95-5 reviewer would have 64 times more votes to have the same review power as the 50-50 reviewer.

We could square it, which makes the review power of a 95-5 trivial no matter how many times they review.  (requires billions of times more review to match a 50-50 reviewer), but that might be too much.

Comment: This "review power" seems to assume that the *correct* accept-reject ratio is 1:1. I don't think that is necessarily true - I think it's likely to be different for each queue.

Comment: @AndrewMedico That portion is simply trying to measure the Shannon entropy information generated by the choice of the reviewer: someone who rejects half the time and accepts half the time generates maximal information per choice (a full bit).  Someone who always rejects or accepts generates none.  Someone who accepts 75% of the time generates less information.  You can add a factor reflecting the reviewer's ability to pass tests if you also want a qualify factor: I just went with experience & information per click, because those are easy things to measure.