# Raise an automatic moderator flag when someone approves an edit suggestion otherwise unanimously rejected as spam/vandalism

Tags: feature-request, flags, suggested-edits, spam

According to [this comment from ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317987/what-flags-are-automatically-raised-by-the-system#comment315459_317988) (deleted now) no auto flag is raised when someone approves an edit that is rejected by every other reviewer as *spam or vandalism*. The rejection description for that is

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.

Perhaps the spam approver misclicked. Or maybe it was actually dangerously stupid robo-reviewing.
The only way for a user to investigate this is by checking this reviewer's profile to find more instances of robo-reviewing, and then raise a moderator flag explaining the whole situation.

Could the system assist us on that and make sure that moderators are informed when such a review (1 approval, 3 rejections as *spam/vandalism*) happens?  This wouldn't apply to other more pedestrian rejections reasons (like *No improvement*).

Comment: TBH I think an auto-flag for that doesn't go far enough. Someone with a pattern of approving spam-rejected posts needs to be review banned until a mod can sort out what happened.

Comment: It's an outside concern, but what if you get a group of people that basically track another person's reviews and get them repeatedly flagged for vandalism or spam even if they aren't?

Comment: @Makoto, you mean they are rejecting valid edits intentionally? Sounds like abuse and cause for suspension themselves.

Comment: @Makoto I would think that the moderators would notice how non-destructive the edits were.  And then a quick glance to how the flag came up would lead them to probably suspend the gang of 3 who rejected as spam.  If the flags aren't warranted, the mods can just ignore them.

Comment: @Makoto Then this group of person has successfully attracted a moderator's attention, and will be _dealt with_ (godfather voice).

Comment: Well...that allays *my* concerns.

Comment: @Andy Be careful about too strongly condemning "rejecting valid edits intentionally."  Keep in mind that If there were a perfectly clear-cut, unambiguous rule for what's a valid edit and what isn't, we wouldn't need human beings to review them.  So it's quite possible that someone would intentionally reject an edit that they think is no good even though it looks perfectly valid to you, or vice versa.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

My gut tells me this is going to fire off a lot of flags, probably more than any other system-generated flag we get. However, most of these will probably be useful signal, as compared to the noise in the other automatic flags.

The problem is going to be what we do with these flags. Based on my experience with manually banning reviewers, most of these users will have been caught and banned or will be caught soon by review audits. There's not much more that moderators should do for those, and we have to visit each user's profile to see if they are currently banned or have been banned since the flag was cast. Perhaps all such flags for a user could be removed upon a manual or system-imposed review ban.

For those that aren't caught by the system, the review ban workflow for moderators [is pretty bad right now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272472/better-review-audits-better-review-ban-tools/272505#272505). It takes a lot of time and effort to dig into someone's review history, determine if a ban is justified, figure out ban durations, and apply a review ban.

I'd like to see some kind of link in the troubling review that would make this a one-click action. Maybe a button we could click next to a user's name that would [trigger a retroactive audit failure for that review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267951/posts-destroyed-as-spam-should-trigger-a-retroactive-audit-failure-for-previous)? The system could then calculate whether a ban needed to be applied, and for how long, saving us a bunch of effort. In fact, that might not be a bad thing to have for all reviews that happened within the last 30 days, if we come across really troubling ones through various means.

Comment: I expect that a page listing users with "questionable" edit reviews in the last 30 days, showing the number of "issue" for each user, along with being able to filter out users that have been baned since the edit review etc, would be more useful then a flag per "questionable" edit review.

After all we care a lot more about someone with lots of "questionable" edit review then someone with just one.

Maybe even include all users where the two other reviewers disagree with them on a lot of reviews.

Comment: Perhaps we'd want to have the automatic flag after the Nth time that this happens, rather than *every* time someone approves a review eventually rejected as spam?  Would that remove some of the noise?

Comment: @Servy - I don't think noise is going to be as much of a problem with these, based on looking at a bunch of these kinds of reviews. The problem is what we do with this signal. Many if not most of these reviewers will be handled by the system through audits, and the decision-making process for moderators on the rest is somewhat painful at present. The ability to impose manual audit failures at the point of review could be a way to ease some of this.

Comment: @IanRingrose - A kind of "leaderboard" for bad reviewers, using various heuristics, is something that I know I've discussed with SE employees and is something they have been investigating. We have some information about bad review patterns among reviewers in the advanced review stats, but not with this specificity.

Comment: Automatically use these flags to get them banned earlier. Count each as a failed review audit?

Comment: @BradLarson Is it true that even mods can only review ban for 30 days? Maybe some of this could be alleviated if we allowed review bans up to a year or two.

Comment: @Magisch - *whistles* http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275736/review-bans-should-escalate-beyond-30-days

Comment: @BradLarson I mean only by mods. I don't trust the audit system to make that call. I do however trust the moderators that we elected.