# Better Edit Review Audits to guide Reviewers

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, review-audits

During my activity in the [suggested edits review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history) I have often seen robo-reviewers that seem to approve everything, only rejecting the (obvious) audits, thus they never get review banned.

Furthermore I suspect that some reviewers do not know that one should reject certain edits (like [plagiarized tag wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313486/lets-stop-tag-wiki-plagiarism)), because they may have totally missed the review guidelines.

This can lead to approved edits that significantly [change](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11526471) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11526648), [fix code in questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6599437), introduce [plagiarized](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11735821) [content](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11578850), are [totally](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11735718) [no](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11526441) [improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11817132) [whatsoever](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11790930), or even [mess things up](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11802919).

The current audits just check whether you are [sleeping](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11817573) or not, but they don't enforce the rules for suggested edits.

I'd suggest to implement review audits that use real rejected edits instead of those auto-generated edits.
For instance edits that have been rejected with 3:0 or 3:1 votes could be used for audits. And if someone fails such an audit, it should be pointed out why the edit was originally rejected.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was lazier OR more work to auto-generate 'edits' to be used as review audits.

Comment: Yes, this makes a lot of sense. Side-note: this is exactly why I tend to "Reject And Edit" more than "Reject"; I know I will have the final word and not let robo approve it behind.

Comment: @CubeJockey Almost certainly more work.  What that work got them was proposed edits that are so obviously bad no sane reviewer could ever possibly argue that the audit incorrectly failed them.  When you recycle real reviews (or even base the reviews on mod actions) there simply will be times, however rare they are, where the action that the review thinks is correct is really wrong, as we've seen from the audits in every other queue.  Of course, much easier audits also means much worse reviewers will pass them.

Comment: Mhm, the dev hours spent to prevent that time loss (managing those rare scenarios) leads to a greater waste in terms of site quality as a result of passed bad-quality edits.

Comment: @CubeJockey Unfortunately, those scenarios aren't rare. I just went through the suggested edit queue and at least 20 of the 30 were like this.

Comment: Related: [Raise an automatic moderator flag when someone approves an edit suggestion otherwise unanimously rejected as spam/vandalism](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318021/4320665).  That could be tweeked to provide audits similar to your proposal.

Comment: similar requests at MSE: [Add “too minor” audits to Suggested Edits review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183977/165773) and [Add more and better audits to suggested edits by drawing from “maximally unanimous” reviews](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267165/165773)

Comment: Given some of the cr*p I've seen approved, even 3:1 or 3:0 (!!)  I don't want to use real cases as audits. I suggest to [generate new types of audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272518/generate-new-types-of-audits-for-the-suggested-edits-queue) instead.

Comment: If more audits are added, they should make audits that change only the post in a certain view, so some that only change the markdown, or some that only change the rendered output, this way people need to review better to see them

Answer (score 6):

I like the idea of using 3:0 rejected posts as a test.  3:1 strikes me as high risk.

An even more reliable approach would be to take 3:0 rejected posts and put them back in the queue.  If they got rejected *again*, they could be used for audits.

The trouble with the current audits is that I can spot them a mile off - so I imagine the robo-approvers can too.

Comment: Im not sure about that. I think SE audits would have to be hand picked. So many edits get either approved or rejected based on who is reviewing them, its a can of worms.

Comment: Sending a rejected edit through the queue twice could be an option to make sure they really need to be rejected. @Magisch afaik someone from SO said that hand picking audits is not an option, since this would require to much manual work, as you need hundredths of different audits.