# Review Auditing too highly weighted toward Spam

Tags: discussion, review-audits, spam

When doing triage reviews, I find a lot of audit reviews are for spam questions. Not sure what the percentage is, but I'd guess around a third of audit questions are spam. In the 'wild' though I've only ever seen one real spam question.

Questions are far more likely to require closing because of low effort, unclear or the other reasons. This may be a result of the tags I most often answer - WordPress attracts the noobest of the noobs - but I don't think so.

On top of that, I think spam is really easy to spot, compared to say, a question that toes the line between too broad and suitable. We don't really need to be tested on it as often as we are in my opinion.

What do people think? Should we shift some weight away from spam questions toward other types of 'deplorables'?

**EDIT** - Here's a perfect example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

You'd have to be on life support to not realise that is spam. I knew straight away this was going to be an audit question. Guess what - it was. What is the point of wasting reviewers time with this?

Comment: I think this is in part caused by the difficulty of identifying audit cases for other problem cases. Totally agree with the concept though, my ideas are at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272472/better-review-audits-better-review-ban-tools

Comment: Spam elimination is widely regarded as one of the most critical and useful moderation activities.  Hard to see what the point could be of *not* teaching reviewers how to do the most important review task.  Is it just because they fail the audit often?  They do, spammers are pretty good at hiding their spam in links.  But that's just an argument to add *more* spam audits :)

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not proposing _not_ teaching reviewers how to review spam. Just putting less weight to it in the reviewer audits. _Is it just because they fail the audit often?_ - I have no idea how to even find that out. I doubt I could even view that at 1697 rep. Just because it is important doesn't mean we need to go on and on about it. Basic arithmetic is important too, but I don't need to get tested on that every week.

Comment: @Flexo true enough. And if you look at Magisch'es answer it seems identifying good audit cases for spam is difficult too. Seems the difficulty of spotting spam goes from trivial, up a steep learning curve to very difficult for some posts. Using the trivial examples as spam review audits is pointless, but using the difficult examples will trip up otherwise competent reviews. Quite the conundrum.

Comment: "In the 'wild' though I've only ever seen one real spam question." - spam gets deleted way faster than other types of crap. The ratio of how much you see "in the wild" vs. how much gets posted is much lower for spam than other crap types.

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238647/dont-use-spam-post-as-audits-in-the-low-quality-review-queue?s=1|1.4908

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I agree with this, and there is a further problem there.

There are lots of ultimately spam posts that are spam and are destroyed not because of the specific content of that one post (it may even be an answer, but includes a known spam link and/or the user has been posting a link on every answer enough to make a mod nuke it).

In these cases, it's not very fair to expect reviewers to know the history of X spam website or Y notorious spammer user. Sometimes spam is even hidden in the punctuation of a copied answer. That makes it even more unfair to the reviewers.

Spammers have been using the tactic of copy-pasting actual answers from the same thread and adding their spurious spam links to it for a while, and that makes it unreasonably difficult to suss out such a post to the average out-of-context reviewer, who cannot be expected to have working knowledge of the hundreds of pretty devious tactics that spammers on SE like to use to conceal themselves.

Comment: Generally I'd agree and history of X is hard, but a lot of the ones with history follow the same small set of patterns and stink even if you don't know the specific history.

Comment: @Flexo What about the one where a spammer copies an upvoted answer verbatim and hides a link to a spam website somewhere in there where another link used to be? Or hiding links in punctuation?

Comment: This just means that every good review includes inspecting the markdown.  If most reviewers aren't doing this, maybe it calls for a reminder banner shown during review, but there's no obligation to make audits easier just because review is hard.  The audits are no harder than real review tasks!

Answer (score 11):

In fact, I would propose removing spam questions from the audit system altogether.  On one hand, like you say, some of them are perhaps too easy to spot; on the other, the ones which aren't will often require a significant bit of context to decide.

We see that here, too; many "I failed an audit" questions are because of this - a spam message was presented, but correctly tagging it as spam would require more effort than most audit questions (after all, we are supposed to judge by the merit of the individual question, not based on other actions by the same OP, which is often required in order to properly diagnose a well-disguised spam campaign).

Comment: Agreed. Except I would make spam 1 - 2% of the audit questions, just to remind reviewers that it is one of the things they should be looking for.

Comment: Also links and names in spam questions are leaved as original, so spam in review audit continues to be spam and is forced to be read by reviewing people. That is unfair that system forces active user to read spam.