# Is there a flaw in audits or am I missing the point?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, review-audits

Yesterday I was doing some reviewing.  I am aware of audits, which are tests to check if the user pays attention or not. I was given [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15766750) and asked if it should be closed or not. I'm not sure what the original reason for closing (which was not `duplicate`) was, but there was a comment (first comment) by the user who asked the question:

> *New updated question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124275/alternative-to-css-grid-layout-but-not-tables-ii)*

So I visited the link and it was the same question with slight modifications. Then I voted for `Close as duplicate` and system responded with

> This was a test, you didn't pass etc.

I can't understand what I did wrong. Why did I fail this audit?

Comment: "Is there a flaw in audits" - yes, more than one. Rest assured you didn't fail the audit, the audit failed you.

Comment: Audits are a flawed system whose only redeeming characteristic is that they are better than the other easily realizable alternatives.

Comment: Possible solution: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272472/better-review-audits-better-review-ban-tools/272505

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, audits are flawed in many ways. Everybody fails them occasionally, unless they cheat (which is easy - but still more effort than people who don't pay attention at *all* are willing to spend).

But! They still serve their purpose. They don't exist to *prevent* improper reviewing, just to keep it to a manageable level.

Comment: Some of us never fail them, because some of us got so irritated by this stupid system years ago that we stopped doing audits. This is a case in point.

Comment: @EJP Unless you meant "stopped doing reviews", I'm not sure how you can not do audits.

Comment: @MrLister (I think that's the joke.)

Comment: @Dragomok (How was I to know...)

Comment: It's not that difficult to avoid audits with a script. Last I checked, whether or not the review is an audit is sent to the client-side, and available through the API (or, at the very least, through the internal, undocumented API that Stack Overflow uses to load reviews). It's a one-time effort, and you can robo-review to your heart's content. Failing that, audits are displayed with 0 score, but you can load the actual question, and it'll show you the real score.

Comment: *"I'm not sure how you can not do audits"* By skipping them. Audits are easy to detect, so one can just skip them.

Answer (score 42):

Speaking in general:

You failed because the question was being used as a *known good question*. A *known good question* is one with no close votes, down votes, and has a score of 5 or more.  So since it was a *known good question* the correct choices are leave open or skip.  Trying to close a *known good question* with any reason is a fail.

Duplicates are a little painful with the review queues.  In triage you can fail an audit by trying to close a question as a dupe just like in the close vote queue.  The problem is that a question can be well received and well written but still be a dupe.  The audit system should ignores these as just because no one else saw/found a dupe does not mean the question is not one.

Comment: It is now such a good one, at the time it has already close vote (I was there for review the close vote). I don't remember down-votes but surely there were not considerable up-votes.

Comment: @Xaqron The system creates fake close votes when doing an audit. Those close votes don't count and aren't real, but it makes it look like it is to see whether you will just believe other people (robo-review) or actually review the question.

Comment: It system adds fake close-votes and maybe down-votes (at least there are not considerable up-votes since you review a question in early stages after publishing) then `known good question` is not meaningful at that early stage.

Comment: @Xaqron the point of audits is kind of where the system becomes inherently broken. They are not designed to be good audits in the traditional sense of what an audit is checking for. They are really just a system-run 'captcha' that messes up otherwise good questions (sometimes) to make them look bad, or vice versa, to make attentive reviewers (which should be everyone) say "wait a minute, what's going on with this?". The dev team's reasoning is, if it makes you stop, check in a new tab, etc., then it has made you pay attention and therefore has done its job.

Comment: A true review audit system would be users (or an automated system) checking reviews that were split, or positive reviews of a negative question, or negative reviews of a positive question.